# C# Windows 10 IoT StreamSocketListener randomly stops listening in release mode

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

Ive been working on some communication between a PC and a Raspberry PI 2 with Windows 10 IoT (build 10586 TH2) using "*StreamSocketListener*". This seems to work fine in debug mode, but when testing the code in release mode the "*StreamSocketListener*" seems to randomly stop responding to requests.

In debug mode, on the RPI2, I've had sessions with 100k requests without a single issue, but when I push the release build it stops, randomly, quite quickly (typically after a couple of hundreds requests). The request is of static type, so the input is the same every time.

Has anyone experienced the same issue, and is there a solution to this problem?

The code is based on this blog post:

[**A simple in-process HTTP server for Windows 8 Metro apps**](http://www.dzhang.com/blog/2012/09/18/a-simple-in-process-http-server-for-windows-8-metro-apps)

```
 private void Listen()
 {
      _listener = new StreamSocketListener();
      _listener.ConnectionReceived += (s, e) => ProcessRequestAsync(e.Socket);
      _listener.BindServiceNameAsync(requestPort.ToString());
 }
private async void ProcessRequestAsync(StreamSocket socket)
    {
        try
        {
            // this works for text only
            StringBuilder request = new StringBuilder();
            using (IInputStream input = socket.InputStream)
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[BufferSize];
                IBuffer buffer = data.AsBuffer();
                uint dataRead = BufferSize;
                while (dataRead == BufferSize)
                {
                    await input.ReadAsync(buffer, BufferSize, InputStreamOptions.Partial);
                    request.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, data.Length));
                    dataRead = buffer.Length;
                }
            }

            using (IOutputStream output = socket.OutputStream)
            {
                string requestMethod = request.ToString().Split('\n')[0];
                string[] requestParts = requestMethod.Split(' ');

                if (requestParts[0] == "GET")
                    await WriteResponseAsync(requestParts[1], output);
                else
                    throw new InvalidDataException("HTTP method not supported: "
                                                   + requestParts[0]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Main ex: " + e);
        }
        RequestCount++;
    }
```

Comment: Interesting... does this still reproduce if you disable .NET Native compilation? (Project properties > BUILD > "Enable .NET Native toolchain")

Comment: It was already set to disabled (unchecked), so what I tried to do was to enable it and run it on the RPI2 in release mode. Now Ive been running nearly 50K requests without any issues... I'm not sure what this tells me, are you able to provide additonal information on this, Matt?

Comment: .NET Native is our new ahead of time compilation stack for UWP applications. The landing page is a bit dated but you can find more information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dotnetnative.aspx. It's not immediately obvious why this clears up the issue but it will be the way UWP applications are served from the Store... so maybe that's good enough? Sorry I couldn't be more immediately useful. :-(

Comment: Ok, Thank you for supplying some more information! I will do some more testing with the setting enabled and disabled, checking whether or not it really fixes the issue. I'll update my question when testing has concluded and most likely accept your comment as the answer.

Comment: Sounds good. If .NET Native gives you other issues, you can mail my team at dotnetnative@microsoft.com. Good luck!

Comment: When the .NET option is enabled that everyone mentions above, I can only get responses to work for 1 minute. I then switched the option off and redeployed and the application works a lot better. Anyway, I have the same problem, but it happens after 2 days or so. I have not found a solution yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a whole day long term testing with the "Compile with .NET Native tool chain" setting turned ON for my UWP project this issue seems to be fixed. When disabling this feature the issue occur after just a couple of minutes.

Because I cant accept a comment as an answer, I'll just answer my own question, and accept it. But all thanks to Matt for pointing me in the right direction.

> Interesting... does this still reproduce if you disable .NET Native compilation? (Project properties > BUILD > "Enable .NET Native toolchain") – Matt Whilden

Comment: Same issue, same inexplicable resolution. The big clue that something is verifiably different with the Native Toolchain is that clients now properly detect/handshake that the connection has been closed when the server disposes the Socket. Previously, `nc myIp myPort` from a client never completed... which makes one wonder if the server had the same issue was leaking sockets. Thanks, @Gnm and @matt-whilden

Answer (score 0):

Matt, Gnm:
I've had exactly the same issue on a RPi3 running on Win-IoT 10.0.14393.693, with a C# code very similar to that in Gnm's first post: StreamSocketListener just stopping to listen to/receive http POST messages while the rest of the app (a web server background service) remained responsive.

Two differences though: 
a) on my machine, that happened already within one minute after app launch, and after only one or two requests. 
b) And it happened with the "Compile with .NET Native Tool chain" option switched to "ON"!

Inspired by Gnm's findings I have now switched this option to OFF, and: my problem appears to be solved. At the time of writing this, the code has been running for one hour only, but it appears to be working and stable now. So, surprisingly, for me the exact opposite of Gnm's solution works...

Answer (score 0):

FYI I had the same problem for a Windows 10 Iot c# app. Mine was fixed by "Compile with .NET Native Tool chain" option switched to "ON" then "Compile with .NET Native Tool chain" option switched to "OFF"!